# Google App Engine Key Class

Tags: python, google-app-engine

What exactly is google app engine's key class? I'm looking at the documentation but it's not really helping. (Python)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Are you asking where it's found? (it's `db.Key`) Or are you asking how it's structured and how to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every entity has either an integer id or a name (string) that uniquely identifies it.  The key is made up of four basic parts:  your app id, the namespace, the kind name, and the integer id or name.  If an entity is a child entity (ie a member of an entity group) the key also contains the parent's kind and id / name.

So a key looks something like this: `AppId:Namespace:[parent Kind:id|name:]Kind:id|name`

[Keys](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html) are discussed in the context of [entity groups](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keysandentitygroups.html), and there is a description in the article about [how entities are stored](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown.html#anc-entitiestable).

Comment: Is it important to understand exactly how db.Key works for developing on the GAE or is it something that won't be needed until some advanced stuff?

Comment: It is important to have an idea about how the datastore works under the covers so that you can properly design your applications.  If you have experience with RDMSes, it is very important to know that the datastore *is **not** SQL*.  Two useful sources of info: 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/ and 
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/datastore/overview.html